# How to redirect to (or enforce) SSL connection?

Tags: php, zend-framework, ssl

I am using Zend Framework(MVC part of it), and need to either redirect user to SSL enabled page or to force SSL from controller somehow and don't quite see how to do that? Maybe someone can share the knowledge?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the PHP header manpage, specifically [this user contribution](http://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.header.php#83448) regarding https handling and redirection.

Answer (score 5):

It's easy to do at the web server level.

In Apache, you'd do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```